# jQuery: reset counter when element is being deleted

Tags: jquery, find, each, counter

So I have a peace of code, here's JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/alexchizhov/T5858/25/

The code below is to reset counter to 1 and add new indexes to each element that is left, but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
// Working with counter
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
         $('<div class="rbPickedCategory" data-pickedcat-name="' + $(this).val() + '"><div class="rbPcCat">' + $(this).attr('data-category-name') + '</div><div class="rbPcSubCat">' + $(this).val() + '</div></div><input type="hidden" name="rbwwsubcategoryhidden[' + countIndexCat + ']" value="' + $(this).val() + '" data-pickedcat-hidden="' + $(this).val() + '"><input type="hidden" name="rbwwcategoryhidden[' + countIndexCat + ']" value="' + $(this).attr('data-category-name') + '" data-catname-hidden="' + $(this).val() + '">').appendTo('div.rbWwCatPicked');
         countShownCats++;
         countIndexCat++;
      } else {
         $('div.rbPickedCategory[data-pickedcat-name="' + $(this).val() + '"]').remove();
         $('input[data-pickedcat-hidden="' + $(this).val() + '"]').remove();
         $('input[data-catname-hidden="' + $(this).val() + '"]').remove();
         countShownCats--;
         countIndexCat--;

         // Reset the counter
         var counter = 1;
         $('input[data-pickedcat-hidden="' + $(this).val() + '"]').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('name', 'rbwwsubcategoryhidden[' + counter + ']');
            counter++;
         });

         var counter = 1;
         $('input[data-catname-hidden="' + $(this).val() + '"]').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('name', 'rbwwcategoryhidden[' + counter + ']');
            counter++;
         });

      }
```

So what I need is when I delete an element, the code finds all elements with data attributes: **`data-catname-hidden`** and **`data-pickedcat-hidden`** and adds a new index to name attribute like: **`rbwwsubcategoryhidden[1]`**, **`rbwwsubcategoryhidden[2]`** and so on.

So what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

---

**EDIT:**

Nevermind, I found a mistake. I was looking for specific elements, but I needed to find all. So I just removed **`$(this).val()`** and it works :) Like this:

```
var counter = 1;
             $('input[data-pickedcat-hidden]').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('name', 'rbwwsubcategoryhidden[' + counter + ']');
                counter++;
             });

             var counter = 1;
             $('input[data-catname-hidden]').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('name', 'rbwwcategoryhidden[' + counter + ']');
                counter++;
             });
```

Comment: Why are you declaring variable `var counter = 1;` multiple times?

Comment: So it resets it after each loop, that works just perfect in all the scripts i ever wrote, so i just use it :)

Comment: your jsfiddle is too large, it's really difficult to read and understand, can you please minimize the fiddle to let us understand it easier?

Comment: even though javascript will not give you an error, you don't need to redeclare the variable counter. Since they are being used in the same scope you can just reset it by referring counter=1 without the var.

Comment: I found solution already :)